# How to use variable returned from click event?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, return

I have JavaScript function which returns array. And I am collecting that array like,

```
<button onclick="var v = onclick1();">Click me</button>
```

I want to use variable v in rest of application.

I tried to make it global but doesn't work.

Can I show text from array v in span which is like,

```
<span id="SP">

</span>
```

Regards

Comment: Why don't you move the logic into the `onclick1` function?

Comment: @Vohuman I have logic in onclick, it is written in some other js file, I want to use it's return value in rest of html.

Comment: So define another function and use the returned value of that function in it. The current logic is broken.

Comment: @Vohuman I have some returned value on click event, how to get that value, then I will use it in other function. First I need to get it?

Comment: Just create a JavaScript function an use the variable  `v` in it.

Comment: @fanTasy Can you please write answer by giving sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB code :

JS

```
  var returnVal;

    function onclick1(){
     // todo write your logic
     var a= [2,2]; // some array to be returned
     returnVal = a;
     document.getElelmentById('SP').innerHtml = returnVal;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <button onclick="onclick1();">Click me</button>
<span id="SP">

</span>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try something like this:

```
<button onclick=" v = onclick1();">Click me</button>

<script>
var v
function onclick1(){
    var a= [2,2];
    return a;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    document.addEventListener("click", function(){ // this part is only to show you that v got the returned vale.
alert(v);
});
});



  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `v` is always going to be scoped to the click handler, and so to make it accessible to the rest of the application, the only way is to have another variable in a higher scope. A possible solution is to have a global object to represent your application, with a `v` property.

```
var yourApp = yourApp || {};
yourApp.v = null;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("yourbutton").addEventListener(function(){
        yourApp.v = onclick1();
    }, false);
}
```

Now, in your other script files, you can refer to `yourApp.v`.

You could just make `v` a global, but having lots of individual globals is not generally good practice (polluting the global scope), however having a single global object, to contain your other variables is acceptable.

Sidenote: I used addEventListener to assign the event handler to your button, which needs an ID `yourbutton` because this is preferred to inline click handlers.